# Android erro utilizando Picasso

Tags: android, imagem, url

Tenho o seguinte código para fazer exibição de imagens através de `URL`

```
public class AdapterListPesquisaResp extends BaseAdapter {

private ImageLoader il;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<ItemListaPesquisaResp> itens;
    Context context;

    public AdapterListPesquisaResp(Context context, ArrayList<ItemListaPesquisaResp> itens) {
        this.itens = itens;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return itens.size();
    }


    public ItemListaPesquisaResp getItem(int position) {
        return itens.get(position);
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ItemSuporte itemHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.texto_resposta_pesquisa, null);

            itemHolder = new ItemSuporte();
            itemHolder.txtTitle = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtnome_resp_pesquisa));
            itemHolder.txtTrabalho = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txttrabalho_resp_pesquisa));
            itemHolder.txtkm = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtkm_resp_pesquisa));
            itemHolder.imgIcon = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemviewfoto_resp_pesquisa));
            itemHolder.imgnota = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_nota_estrela));
            itemHolder.txtkminforma = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView));
            itemHolder.corfundo = ((RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layoutresposta_pesquisa));

            view.setTag(itemHolder);
        } else {
            itemHolder = (ItemSuporte) view.getTag();
        }

        ItemListaPesquisaResp item = itens.get(position);
        if (item.toString() == "Anuncios de trabalho") {
            itemHolder.txtTitle = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtnome_resp_pesquisa));
        } else {
            if (item.getnome().equals("Buscar")) {

                itemHolder.txtTrabalho.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itemHolder.txtkm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itemHolder.imgIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itemHolder.imgnota.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itemHolder.txtkminforma.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itemHolder.txtTitle.setText("Mais");
            }
            else {
                itemHolder.txtTrabalho.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemHolder.txtkm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemHolder.imgIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemHolder.imgnota.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemHolder.txtkminforma.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemHolder.txtTitle.setText(item.getnome());
                itemHolder.txtTrabalho.setText(item.getprofissao());
                itemHolder.txtkm.setText(item.getkm());
                itemHolder.txtkminforma.setText("km");
                if (item.getfoto().equals("")) {

                } else {
                    if (item.getfoto().equals(" ")){

                    }else {
                        Picasso.with(context).load(item.getfoto()).into(itemHolder.imgIcon);  // esta dando erro aqui!
                    }
                }
                itemHolder.imgnota.setImageDrawable(item.getnota());
            }

        }
        return view;
    }

    private class ItemSuporte {

        ImageView imgnota, buscarimg,imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle, txtkminforma;
        public TextView txtkm;
        public TextView txtTrabalho;
        TextView buscar;
        RelativeLayout corfundo;
    }
```

}

O que me  retorne no Logcat é

```
11-20 15:03:30.566      660-660/spac.com.br.jobbroker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.<init>(Picasso.java:635)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:597)
        at spac.com.br.jobbroker.Pesquisa_subs.AdapterListPesquisaResp.getView(AdapterListPesquisaResp.java:111)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2106)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como diz no próprio erro, sua variável **context** está nula, e de fato você não está definindo nenhum valor para ela, que no caso deve ser feita no construtor.

Modifique-o para:

```
public AdapterListPesquisaResp(Context context, ArrayList<ItemListaPesquisaResp> itens) {
    this.itens = itens;
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

Comment: Puts eu nem tinha percebido! Muito obrigado.